# Using AngularJS template tags in Django

Tags: django, angularjs

I'm using `AngularJS` in my `Django` powered webpage and I've encountered a problem. since AngularJS and Django share the same token variables (`{{ variable_name }}`), AngularJS can't recognize its variables in my webpage.

```
<h1>{{ title }}</h1> //this is django variable
<ul class="pagination">
    <li data-ng-repeat="cat in categories" ng-class="{'active': $index==catSelectedIndex}">
        <a data-ng-click="resetPage(cat.id)">{{ cat.name }}</a> //<< cat.name is angular variable
    </li>
</ul>
```

How can I make it work?