# What does {$ ... $} stand for in django templates?

Tags: angularjs, django

I have a Django App with an AngularJS (1.5.8) frontend and stumbled across a notation in the templates that I don't understand. I also can't find any explanation in the Django or AngularJS docs.

```
<div class="form-label">
   {$ ... $}
</div>
```

I know, that one can use `{{ ... }}` for variables, `{% ... %}` for tags or `{# ... #}` for comments. But what is `{$ ... $}` for?

Any ideas?

Comment: This may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27678374/using-angularjs-template-tags-in-django/27678401#27678401

Comment: Thanks @shafik. I found a similar snippet in the code. You saved my day :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a built in template tag. It looks like someone is probably using a custom template tag for angular as angular and Django both use `{{ }}` for their template tags.

Check for something in your code like this:

```
myApp.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
  $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{$');
  $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('$}');
});
```

This is a way of setting custom template tags in angular. See [the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$interpolateProvider)